# Core Data Fetch Request Variable in Xcode 4

Tags: ios, core-data

How do I add a variable to a fetch request in core data in Xcode 4?  Can't find it.

Comment: Someone asked the same question a few months after you did: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7099595/xcode-4-fetch-request-template-variables

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apple has moved it again in the latest XCode.  To use Variables in the Fetch Requests in the Core Data editor, you have to use the "expression" type and manually type it in:

data == $DATA

(in this expression, $DATA is the variable).

Comment: Code example? This is done in the XCode Core Data editor, in the Fetch Request fields...

Answer (score 31):

Select `Expression` from the drop down and enter the expression using a `$` before your substitution variable (`NAME` in the example below). Even if the substitution variable's value is a string, make sure you don't put the variable between quotes, or the substitution will not work.

[image: Fetch predicate with substitution variable]

In your code you refer to the fetch predicate like this (XCode 4.4 and above):

```
NSManagedObjectModel* model = [[context persistentStoreCoordinator] managedObjectModel];
NSFetchRequest* request = [model fetchRequestFromTemplateWithName:templateName
                                            substitutionVariables:@{@"NAME" : name}];
NSError* error = nil;
NSArray* results = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
```

Comment: Ah. They key here is that you don't put `$` before the name in the `substitutionVariables` dictionary.

Comment: In Xcode 9, you need to select Custom Predicate instead of Expression

Answer (score 2):

If by variable you mean pass a value to a fetch request so you delimit the request? Then all you do is declare an NSPredicate.

Something like this:

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"name" inManagedObjectContext:context];
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(attribute == %@)", value];
[request setEntity:entity];
[request setPredicate:predicate];
NSError *error;
NSArray *results = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
[request release];
```

Comment: I created a fetch request in the core data editor.  Used to be you right clicked on the predicate and it let you put a variable in there.  Where did that go?

Comment: To do it through the editor, it's easier if you change the editor style at the bottom right to a list. That way you'll see all the entities in an entity list on the left and all you have to do is click on the entity of interest and add your fetch property in its appropriate section.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're talking about there.  I've tried the different editor styles and I still can't find a way to add a variable to my Fetch Request.

Answer (score 1):

You may have already found a solution but it took me a while and it may save someone else's time so here it is: [the apple documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/XcodeCoreDataTools/Articles/xcdCodeGeneration.html) explains it.

Comment: More precise location is  [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/XcodeCoreDataTools/Articles/xcdPredicateBuilder.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006853-SW1) under "right hand side". But the instruction to "ctrl+click" on the empty field does not result in the context menu the help page displays (in XCode 4.2.1)