# Xcode 4: Fetch Request Template Variables?

Tags: objective-c, core-data, xcode4

In Xcode 3.X, you were supposed to right-click the whitespace in the fetch request template's predicate editor to specify a variable input rather than a hard-coded predicate.

Where is this in XCode 4? I've held option, right-clicked, option-clicked, etc and cannot figure it out....

[image: Variable in Fetch Request Template Editor Predicate]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Core Data Fetch Request Variable in Xcode 4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6270277/core-data-fetch-request-variable-in-xcode-4)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I don't think X4 has the variable anymore.

Instead, I think you have to choose an expression and then provide a variable of the form `$VARNAME`.

For example, given and entity `Alpha` with an attribute `aString`, I created a fetch request template `bobFetch` with an expression of `aString == $TESTVAR`.

```
Alpha *a=[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Alpha" inManagedObjectContext:self.moc];
a.aString=@"steve";
[self saveContext];
NSDictionary *subVars=[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"steve" forKey:@"TESTVAR"];
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest =   [self.managedObjectModel fetchRequestFromTemplateWithName:@"bobRequest" substitutionVariables:subVars];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Alpha" inManagedObjectContext:self.moc];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
```

If logged `fetchRequest` reports:

```
<NSFetchRequest: 0x4d17480> (entity: Alpha; predicate: (aString == "steve"); sortDescriptors: ((null)); type: NSManagedObjectResultType; )
```

... and can then be used normally.

```
NSError *error = nil;
NSArray *fetchedObjects = [self.moc executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
if (fetchedObjects == nil) {
    NSLog(@"fetch error = %@",error);
}
NSLog(@"fetchObjects = %@",fetchedObjects);
```

Kind of clumsy for a graphical environment but it works.

Comment: Actually, you helped me out. I don't use fetch templates very often and hadn't noticed the editor had changed so this let me figure how to do it.

Comment: Why don't you use fetch templates more often? It seems to me that it would make your code much cleaner to define all your model predicates in one place?

Comment: Mostly habit. During development, fetches can go through a lot of evolutions and it's just easier to do that in code for me.

Comment: Fetch request templates can provide a huge performance boost on large data sets. (app. 30-50%)

Answer (score 11):

This has been tweaked in Xcode 4. In order to use substitution variables, you need to choose "Expression" from the popup menu (i.e. instead of an attribute name) and you can enter the equivalent like this: `name == $SEARCH_NAME`

If you were to just enter a $VARIABLE value in the field for each attribute, you'll get the wrong result. In fact, some attributes won't allow that such as Date attributes where you are forced to enter a value.

Of course you can use multiple variables from there on.

Then it's just as before with executing the fetch request:

```
NSString *searchName = @"Mr Squiggle";
NSDictionary *subs = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:searchName forKey:@"SEARCH_NAME"];
NSManagedObjectModel *model = [self managedObjectModel];
NSFetchRequest *req = [model fetchRequestFromTemplateWithName:@"trainerByName" substitutionVariables:subs];
NSError *error = nil;
NSArray *results = [[self managedObjectContext] executeFetchRequest:req error:&error];
NSLog(@"Found %ld record.", [results count]);
```

Note you can also do away with the attributes popup and just click the button on the top right of the editor (looks like lines right beside the default grid view button) and just enter your expression straight away. This is a good way of seeing how some things like dates get translated.